# Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON in my shopping cart

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to add a `localStorage` functionality to my shopping cart, but I just started learning `localStorage` and JSON, so I don't have enough knowledge about it to make it work.

I get this error when I try to convert an `array` of `data(shopping cart items)` into a `string`:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
> --> starting at object with constructor 'Array'
>     --- index 0 closes the circle
> ```

```
function adicionaAoCart(title, price) {

  let linhaCart = document.createElement("div")
  let itensCart = document.getElementsByClassName("itens-cart")[0]
  linhaCart.classList.add("linha-cart")
  let itemNomeCart = itensCart.getElementsByClassName("cart-item-title")
  for (i = 0; i < itemNomeCart.length; i++) {
    if (itemNomeCart[i].innerText == title) {
      alert("This item has already been added.")
      return
    }
  }

  let conteudoCart = `
                    <div class="cart-item cart-column">
                        <span class="cart-item-title">${title}</span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${price}</span>
                        <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">X</button>
                    </div>

                        `
  linhaCart.innerHTML = conteudoCart;
  itensCart.append(linhaCart)
  linhaCart.getElementsByClassName("btn-danger")[0].addEventListener("click", removeCartItem)
  linhaCart.getElementsByClassName("cart-quantity-input")[0].addEventListener("change", quantityChanged)

  cartArray = []
  cartArray.push(itensCart)

  localStorage.setItem('itens', JSON.stringify(cartArray))
  const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itens'))

  data.forEach(item => {
    adicionaAoCart(item)
  })
}
```

Comment: What is `itensCart.push(itensCart)` supposed to do?

Comment: push a shopping cart item into an empty array with the same name. Am i not supposed to make the items an array first so i can convert them into a string with json?

Comment: `itensCart` is not a shopping cart item, it's an empty array.

Comment: In other words, you're trying to push an array into itself.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry. is it fixed now? Now i'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

Comment: I have no idea. Only you can run your code. You haven't given us a [mcve].

Comment: You should store **cartArray** not an **itensCart**.
Now, You've stored an object which has no **forEach** method. **forEach** method belongs to array structure

Comment: Thanks @PatrykFalba, I think i'm on the right track now. It seems the key/value gets added to the localStorage, it even displays the error function alert when i try adding 2 of the same item. But for some reason the items are not showing in the cart modal when i refresh the page. Now i'm trying to figure out why.